# Adding a ribbon button to link to dashboards in Dynamics 365

Tags: dynamics-crm, ribbon, dashboard, dynamics-365

I've worked out how to customize the Dynamics 365 Ribbon by using Ribbon Workbench and add an external url to a button, however what I would like to do is add a button with a link to the 'dashboards' entity. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an unsupported way to achieve this if you want to do it in Ribbon/Command bar button.

Like the same way, how you used the external url in a custom button, use the below urls for dashboards.

URL for All Dashboards:

```
CRM Server URL (for eg https://orgname.crm.dynamics.com) + "/workplace/home_dashboards.aspx?sitemappath=SFA%7cMyWork%7cnav_dashboards"
```

URL for Specific Dashboard:

```
CRM Server URL (for eg https://orgname.crm.dynamics.com) + "/dashboards/dashboard.aspx?dashboardId=[DashboardGUID]&dashboardType=1030&pagemode=iframe"
```

[Read more](https://dynamicsofdynamicscrm.com/2016/02/26/quick-tipopen-dashboards-with-url-in-dynamics-crm-20152016/)

To mention, [Sitemap](http://magnifez.com/2017/05/27/customize-crm-sitemap/) is the supported way to use dashboard navigation.

[image]